# hsqldb: Encryption of an existing database?

Tags: encryption, hsqldb

Do you know a method to encrypt an existing hsql database without loosing it contents?

I want to use it afterwards with the jdbc url

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:<database path>;crypt_key=<key>;crypt_type=blowfish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is by modifying the code and building a special jar that reads the .script in clear text, but does all the writing with encryption.

With the normal jar, execute `SHUTDOWN SCRIPT` on the existing database to turn it into a .script file.

Modify org.hsqldb.persist.Log#processScript() with `Crypto crypto = null;` instead of the existing line. Compile the jar using Ant or Gradle.

Open the database with the encryption URL the special jar and execute `SHUTDOWN`. This will encrypt the database

Use the normal jar to access the encrypted database.

As this is a useful feature, it may be added to future versions of HSQLDB.