# HSQLDB - Changing / removing encryption key

Tags: java, encryption, hsqldb, rdbms

I think that the only way to change or remove the encryption key from a HSQLDB database is to follow a procedure similar to the one explained in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681920/hsqldb-encryption-of-an-existing-database), where an encryption key is added.

What are the steps that are needed to instead change (or remove altogether) the encryption key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily. Use the SQL statement, `SCRIPT <filename.script>` to save the database as a script. You can then connect to the database named `filename`.

Comment: So with this I would remove the encryption key. If instead I wanted to change the key I should encrypt this new database with the procedure I linked to in my question?

Comment: This doe not remove the encryption from the database. It allows you to start an un-encrypted copy of the database. You can then use the other answer to encrypt this copy with a new key.